# Kivy : How to start text from right side in TextInput?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

When I type in `MyFloatInput` TextInput then text start from `right` side of TextInput,It's working perfect
but I set value of `MyFloatInput` TextInput from `.py` then it start from left side.It doesn't show in right side.
Can someone tell me what is wrong with code?

## test.py

```
import kivy

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (400, 100)


class MyFloatInput(TextInput):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyFloatInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.multiline = False

    def right_adjust(self, text):
        max_width = self.width - self.padding[0] - self.padding[2]
        new_text = text
        text_width = self._get_text_width(new_text, self.tab_width, self._label_cached)
        while text_width < max_width:
            new_text = ' ' + new_text
            text_width = self._get_text_width(new_text, self.tab_width, self._label_cached)
        while text_width >= max_width:
            if new_text[0] != ' ':
                break
            else:
                new_text = new_text[1:]
                text_width = self._get_text_width(new_text, self.tab_width, self._label_cached)
        return new_text

    def delete_selection(self, from_undo=False):
        if not self._selection:
            return
        cr = self.cursor[1]
        initial_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        a, b = self._selection_from, self._selection_to
        if a > b:
            a, b = b, a
        super(MyFloatInput, self).delete_selection(from_undo=from_undo)
        cur_text = self._lines[cr]
        super(MyFloatInput, self)._refresh_text(self.right_adjust(cur_text))
        final_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        self.cursor = self.get_cursor_from_index(final_len - (initial_len - b))

    def do_backspace(self, from_undo=False, mode='bkspc'):
        cc, cr = self.cursor
        initial_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        super(MyFloatInput, self).do_backspace(from_undo=from_undo, mode=mode)
        cc, cr = self.cursor
        cur_text = self._lines[cr]
        super(MyFloatInput, self)._refresh_text(self.right_adjust(cur_text))
        final_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        self.cursor = self.get_cursor_from_index(final_len - (initial_len-cc) + 1)

    def insert_text(self, the_text, from_undo=False):
        cc, cr = self.cursor
        cur_text = self._lines[cr]
        initial_len = len(cur_text)
        new_text = self.right_adjust(cur_text[:cc] + the_text + cur_text[cc:])
        try:
            num = float(new_text) # throw exception if new_text is invalid float
        except ValueError:
            return
        self._lines[cr] = ''
        super(MyFloatInput, self).insert_text(new_text, from_undo=from_undo)
        final_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        self.cursor = self.get_cursor_from_index(final_len - (initial_len-cc))

    def set_right_adj_text(self, text):
        num = float(text)  # throws exception if text is invalid float
        self._refresh_text(self.right_adjust(text))

    def on_text(self, instance, text):
        #num = float(text)  # throws exception if text is invalid float
        self._refresh_text(self.right_adjust(text))

class Testing(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Testing, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: setattr(self.test, 'text', str(100)))

class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
Testing:
    test:test
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint_x: .6

            Label:
                text: "No."
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
                size_hint_x: .2

            MyFloatInput:
                size_hint_x: .6
                id : test
```

Comment: Python-xxx tags should only be used if the code refers to a problem or requirement that only works in a particular version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made significant changes to the `MyFloatInput` class. It now no longer needs the `string` import. It now handles deleting a selection, and you can now set the text from a .py file using the `set_right_adj_text("some text")` method. Here is the improved class:

```
class MyFloatInput(TextInput):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyFloatInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.multiline = False

    def right_adjust(self, text):
        max_width = self.width - self.padding[0] - self.padding[2]
        new_text = text
        text_width = self._get_text_width(new_text, self.tab_width, self._label_cached)
        while text_width < max_width:
            new_text = ' ' + new_text
            text_width = self._get_text_width(new_text, self.tab_width, self._label_cached)
        while text_width >= max_width:
            if new_text[0] != ' ':
                break
            else:
                new_text = new_text[1:]
                text_width = self._get_text_width(new_text, self.tab_width, self._label_cached)
        return new_text

    def on_size(self, instance, value):
        super(MyFloatInput, self).on_size(instance, value)
        if len(self._lines) == 0:
            return True
        cc, cr = self.cursor
        cur_text = self._lines[cr]
        initial_len = len(cur_text)
        super(MyFloatInput, self)._refresh_text(self.right_adjust(cur_text))
        final_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        self.cursor = self.get_cursor_from_index(final_len - (initial_len - cc))
        return True

    def delete_selection(self, from_undo=False):
        if not self._selection:
            return
        cr = self.cursor[1]
        initial_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        a, b = self._selection_from, self._selection_to
        if a > b:
            a, b = b, a
        super(MyFloatInput, self).delete_selection(from_undo=from_undo)
        cur_text = self._lines[cr]
        super(MyFloatInput, self)._refresh_text(self.right_adjust(cur_text))
        final_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        self.cursor = self.get_cursor_from_index(final_len - (initial_len - b))

    def do_backspace(self, from_undo=False, mode='bkspc'):
        cc, cr = self.cursor
        initial_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        super(MyFloatInput, self).do_backspace(from_undo=from_undo, mode=mode)
        cc, cr = self.cursor
        cur_text = self._lines[cr]
        super(MyFloatInput, self)._refresh_text(self.right_adjust(cur_text))
        final_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        self.cursor = self.get_cursor_from_index(final_len - (initial_len-cc) + 1)

    def insert_text(self, the_text, from_undo=False):
        cc, cr = self.cursor
        cur_text = self._lines[cr]
        initial_len = len(cur_text)
        new_text = self.right_adjust(cur_text[:cc] + the_text + cur_text[cc:])
        try:
            num = float(new_text) # throw exception if new_text is invalid float
        except ValueError:
            return
        self._lines[cr] = ''
        super(MyFloatInput, self).insert_text(new_text, from_undo=from_undo)
        final_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        self.cursor = self.get_cursor_from_index(final_len - (initial_len-cc))

    def set_right_adj_text(self, text):
        num = float(text)  # throws exception if text is invalid float
        self._refresh_text(self.right_adjust(text))
```

Comment: Thanks.I updated code.When increase `TextInput` size and value pass from `.py` file then it doesn't show right align it shows in center

Comment: I added an `on_size()` method to handle size changes. It is reflected in the edited code above

Comment: What do you mean by "typing not working properly"? It seems to work properly for me.

Comment: How can I add `arabic_reshaper` and `bidi` to it?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any way to do it using the options available for `TextInput`. But it can be done by extending `TextInput`. Here is a `MyFloatInput` class:

```
import string

class MyFloatInput(TextInput):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyFloatInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.multiline = False

    def insert_text(self, theText, from_undo=False):
        if theText not in string.digits and theText != '.':
            return
        if '.' in self.text and theText == '.':
            return

        maxWidth = self.width - self.padding[0] - self.padding[2]
        cc, cr = self.cursor
        curText = self._lines[cr]
        new_text = curText[:cc] + theText + curText[cc:]
        textWidth = self._get_text_width(new_text, self.tab_width, self._label_cached)
        while textWidth < maxWidth:
            new_text = ' ' + new_text
            textWidth = self._get_text_width(new_text, self.tab_width, self._label_cached)
        while textWidth >= maxWidth:
            if new_text[0] != ' ':
                break
            else:
                new_text = new_text[1:]
                textWidth = self._get_text_width(new_text, self.tab_width, self._label_cached)
        self._lines[cr] = ''
        self.cursor = (0,cr)
        super(MyFloatInput, self).insert_text(new_text, from_undo=from_undo)
```

This should do what you want and does the `float` filtering as well. To use it, include it in your .py file and replace the `TextInput` section of your .kv file with:

```
        MyFloatInput:
            size_hint_x: .2
```

Note that this only works for single line input, so the `__init__` method sets `multiline` to `False`. This code uses methods and variables that start with `_`, so the code may break if the `TextInput` class gets updated.

Comment: @macsontaylor change `super()` to `super(MyFloatInput, self)` and it should work in python2, what's the problem with running it in python2?

Comment: @macsontaylor `import string`